# How to find the required dependency software on CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to install scientific computation software on CentOS. According to the [manual](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Toolchains), I need to install `amdfftw-3.1` but when I try to search `amdfftw` with `yum`, it returns nothing:

```
[beta@login03 0]$ yum search amdfftw
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
Warning: No matches found for: amdfftw
No matches found
```

My question is:
On CentOS or Linux systems, how should I find the right software which I'm required to install?
And I often see that when I'm required to install a package, for example, `BLAS`, it turns out I need to install a library, `sudo yum install libblas-dev`, how should I know whether I should install the software or the library?

Comment: we can't tell you what toolchains to use – you'd only want to use the amdfftw if that reflects your scientific needs and your hardware platform.

Comment: anyway, the table does not claim there's an amdfftw package – you will have to build amd-fftw yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `yum deplist <package>` to get all the depencies

Comment: not a package, so can't do that.

Comment: As Marcus said, `Warning: No matches found for: amdfftw` (for the OP's example software).

Comment: Here a [link](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Installing_VASP.6.X.X) that list all the requirements.